# Media query not working properly on chrome. But ok on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Why me red on chrome devtools iphone5(width: 320px)</h1>
```

In chrome debug tools,code above will show like 
[image]

But in firefox,it looks like：
[image]

By the way, my chrome is the latest version
[image]

So should I do some configuration to make my chrome work ?

Comment: there is no problem with this  code , i think you need to remove your broswer catch

Comment: First make sure `viewport` meta tag is set, second set emulator to `100%` currently it is `41%`

Comment: @Naila brower cache?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey `viewport` works for me.